Convert formulas to values using ssconvert
Is it possible to convert an Excel file to a gnumeric XML format performing all calculations before converting?
I know how to convert Excel to XML but I'd like the equivalent of copy all, paste values to happen before the conversion.
I also know that the calculation is performed if the output is in other formats such as HTML.
However I'd like XML output and calculations done.
Is that doable?
